# java arrays, executing positive and negative numbers

Tags: java, arrays

I need to execute positive and negative numbers from an array list. I also need to execute duplicates from array list. I will post my java code and hope someone can tell me why I can't run this code. Is there something missing in it? Thanks in advance.

```
 public static void main(String[] args) {

    int i, a, b;
    int[] array1 = new int[20];//{12,23, -22, 0, 43,545, -4, -55,43, 12,0, -999, -87

    array1[0] = 12;
    array1[1] = 23;
    array1[2] = -22;
    array1[3] = 0;
    array1[4] = 43;
    array1[5] = 545;
    array1[6] = -4;
    array1[7] = -55;
    array1[8] = 43;
    array1[9] = 12;
    array1[10] = 0;
    array1[11] = -991;
    array1[12] = -87;

    int[] arrayPlus = new int[20];
    int[] arrayMinus = new int[20];


    a = b = 0;


    for (i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
        if (array1 > 0 || array1 == 0) {
            arrayPlus[a] = array1;
            a++;
        } else {
            arrayMinus = array1;
            b++;
        }

    }
    System.out.println("Positive array numbers");
    for (i = 0; i < a; i++) {
        System.out.println(arrayPlus);
    }


    System.out.println("");

    System.out.println("Negative array numbers");
    for (i = 0; i < b; i++) {
        System.out.println(arrayMinus);
    }

  }
}
```

Comment: What's the issue with the code? Your comparison is wrong. `array1 > 0` should be `array1[i] > 0`. Indexing. Similar issue inside the if condition, and assigning to `arrayMinus`.

Comment: You should try to learn the [basics of arrays](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

Comment: How do you "execute" a number? What do you mean by "[execute](http://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/execute)"? "to kill"? "to do or perform"? Something else?

Comment: You can't run this code because it doesn't compile. If you have trouble understanding the compile errors, you should show the error, show what line it occurs on, and ask a specific question about it. First compile error is *"The operator > is undefined for the argument type(s) int[], int"* in the line `if (array1 > 0 || array1 == 0){`. Is that your question?

Comment: Yes Andreas I need to perform positive and negative numbers from an array

Answer (score 1):

You are comparing whole table array1 with integer. You can't do that. You should compare only one element of the array with 0. That mean you should use array1[i] instead.

Answer (score 1):

Try to change this block:

```
  if (array1 > 0 || array1 == 0){
  arrayPlus[a] =array1;
  ...
 {arrayMinus =array1;
  ...
 }

for (i = 0; i < a; i++) {
System.out.println(arrayPlus);}

 System.out.println("Negative array numbers");
 for (i = 0; i < b; i++) {
 System.out.println(arrayMinus);}

 }
```

With this:

```
   if (array1[a] > 0 || array1[a] == 0){
   arrayPlus[a] =array1[a];
  ...
  {arrayMinus[a] =array1[a];

 ...
 for (i = 0; i < a; i++) {
System.out.println(arrayPlus[a]);}

  System.out.println("Negative array numbers");
for (i = 0; i < b; i++) {
System.out.println(arrayMinus[b]);}

}
```

And for more learn `array` go in [link](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/tutorial/java/nutsandbolts/arrays.html)

Answer (score 0):

Try to instead of code

```
for (i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
    if (array1 > 0 || array1 == 0) {
        arrayPlus[a] = array1;
        a++;
    } else {
        arrayMinus = array1;
        b++;
    }

}
```

Use following code:

```
for (i = 0; i < 13; i++) {
    if (array1[i] > 0 || array1[i] == 0) {
        arrayPlus[a] = array1[i];
        a++;
    } else {
        arrayMinus[b] = array1[i];
        b++;
    }
}
```

You should work with elements of arrays (array1[i], arrayMinus[b]) not with  whole arrays (array1, arrayMinus). Some problem with code:

```
for (i = 0; i < a; i++) {
    System.out.println(arrayPlus); // use arrayPlus[i]
}


System.out.println("");

System.out.println("Negative array numbers");
for (i = 0; i < b; i++) {
    System.out.println(arrayMinus); // use arrayMinus[i]
}
```

Comment: Works fine Viacheslav. Thank You for your help. I appreciate it.

Comment: Can You please provide a way to find duplicate elements from this array ?

Comment: I think, the easiest way is sort this array using Arrays.sort() and later copy to new array only if element not equals previous: for (int i = 0, j =0; i < a.length(); i++) if(i == 0 || a[i-1] != a[i]) {new[j] = a[i]; j++}